# Text -> Diagram Tool

Tags: uml, diagramming

I'm looking for an diagram tool for **producing diagrams from text**.  I only really need sequence and state type diagrams for now, but I'm curious as to what people would recommend?    I need something which is standalone, not a web based tool that works on Linux, OSX and Windows.

Comment: Not programming related?

Comment: Ditaa is a good example of such a tool - http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I don't see how it isn't programming related...

Comment: So you want something that takes text and produces drawings? Or do you want something that produces ASCII art drawings?

Comment: Ok a little misleading, I'm looking for a tool that takes ASCII text and outputs images.

Comment: An exhaustive list of such tools can be founde here: http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml-tools#textual

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692985/text-diagram-tool for the reverse. i.e. generating text diagrams

Answer (score 20):

I'm not positive what you mean by "producing diagrams from text", but if you mean a tool where diagrams are specified by a text file, [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is good. If you mean something that literally converts ascii art like

```
+--------+   +-------+    +-------+
|        | --+ ditaa +--> |       |
|  Text  |   +-------+    |diagram|
|Document|   |!magic!|    |       |
|     {d}|   |       |    |       |
+---+----+   +-------+    +-------+
    :                         ^
    |       Lots of work      |
    +-------------------------+
```

to a graphic:

[image]

You can try [ditaa](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/) (that ascii art is from their website, so it's a good example of the input format it expects)

Comment: +1 Ah good old dot; had a professor in college that loved that tool for BNF Expression Trees

Comment: Any online tool like Graphviz?

Comment: @Sobiaholic, I found on https://xosh.org/text-to-diagram/ online tool for Graphviz - http://www.webgraphviz.com/

Answer (score 13):

Look at PlantUML, LaTeX+MetaUML, sdedit, TextUML, yUML, ...
There is a plenty of quite good tools.

Comment: PlantUML looks pretty good, thanks...

Comment: I'm the author of the **PlantUML Gizmo**, which is a free add-on for [Google Docs](https://sites.google.com/site/plantumlgizmo) or [Microsoft Word](https://code.google.com/p/plantuml-word-add-in-vsto/). It allows using PlantUML in those documents.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend TextDiagram http://weidagang.github.com/text-diagram/. It creates UML sequence diagram from pure text.

Example input

```
object April Todd Monad
note left of April: Lunch is ready
April->Todd: Todd, what are you doing?
note right of Todd: Programming @_@
Todd->April: Well, I'm programming.
April->Monad: And you?
Monad->April: I'm reading book.
April->Monad: Good boy!
note right of Monad: Smile ^_^
```

produces:

```
               +-------+                       +-------+               +-------+
               | April |                       | Todd  |               | Monad |
               +-------+                       +-------+               +-------+
-----------------\ |                               |                       |
| Lunch is ready |-|                               |                       |
------------------ |                               |                       |
                   |                               |                       |
                   | Todd, what are you doing?     |                       |
                   |------------------------------>|                       |
                   |                               | ------------------\   |
                   |                               |-| Programming @_@ |   |
                   |                               | -------------------   |
                   |                               |                       |
                   |        Well, I'm programming. |                       |
                   |<------------------------------|                       |
                   |                               |                       |
                   | And you?                      |                       |
                   |------------------------------------------------------>|
                   |                               |                       |
                   |                               |     I'm reading book. |
                   |<------------------------------------------------------|
                   |                               |                       |
                   | Good boy!                     |                       |
                   |------------------------------------------------------>|
                   |                               |                       | ------------\
                   |                               |                       |-| Smile ^_^ |
                   |                               |                       | -------------
                   |                               |                       |
```

Comment: @slm it's moved to http://weidagang.github.com/text-diagram/

Comment: Any idea if this supports multithreading? I have a feeling the answer is no :(

Answer (score 8):

I'd recomment [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/index.html). It is an excellent tools that lets you draw all kinds of UML diagrams from simple textual specification.

Answer (score 0):

[EventStudio](http://www.eventhelix.com/EventStudio/) supports generation of sequence diagrams and collaboration diagrams from text input.